# Does Bar Interval Matter for Strategy Performance?

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

When backtesting the same strategy on charts of difference bar interval length, I notice that the performance of the strategy changes:

Day-Bar Interval
[image]

15min-Bar Interval
[image]

Is this really the case when creating a bot that bar interval impacts potential performance? My own assumption is yes. Take the following example:

```
// Compute a 10-bar and 50-bar Simple Moving Average (SMA)
fastAverage = ta.sma(close, 10)
slowAverage = ta.sma(close, 50)
```

The slow average takes the last 50 bars, the fast takes the last 10 bars. As per the screenshots above, those bars could be 15 mins each, or 1 day each in length, which would obviously impact signals and performance.

Is my understanding correct?

How do we control the bar intervals that our bots work with?

Comment: How you control the bar intervals is simple: When you attach your script to a chart, you are attaching it to a specific timeframe (say to a 15 minute chart). The easiest way to "resolve" this problem is to duplicate your script, tailor it to a different timeframe and attach it to those different timeframes. This is not ideal, hard to maintain, but good for beginners as you are shifting the problem to a different dimension. Instead of a complicated Pine script you will need discipline and extra work managing your different scripts and their history.

Comment: @karatedog So you're saying the chart to which a script is attached controls the intervals/granularity at which the bot will look at?

Comment: Yes. A chart always have a timeframe, which defines how many bars (data points) it will have. If you have a chart with a 1H timeframe,  and your script runs on every bar's close (this is the default) it will run on every hour. If you attach the same script to the daily chart, it will run when the daily bar closes, hence, once a day.

Comment: I dare to say no strategy works the same on different timeframes. Price level strategies could be the closest to this "same success" but nobody runs a price level strategy on bars/candles but on a tick-level (so the fastest available data level) as higher time frames would make it worse (hence, neither this works with the same success)

Answer (score 0):

Your script will be executed on each bar. And each bar has a different volume, high, low, open, close price. So, the results will of course be different.

Some indicators are tailored for long term trades, some for short term trades. Each indicator is different.

You need to do some work with your indicator. You need to find out what are the best settings and what is the best timeframe. Then you can set up your bot accordingly.

You can also do multi timeframe analysis. So that, you are not limited with one timeframe. You can request data from other timeframes. For that, you can use :

```
request.security()
```

> Requests data from another symbol and/or timeframe.

Or

```
request.security_lower_tf()
```

> Requests data from a specified symbol from a lower timeframe than the
> chart's. The function returns an array containing one element for each
> closed lower timeframe intrabar inside the current chart's bar. On a
> 5-minute chart using a `timeframe` argument of "1", the size of the
> array will usually be 5, with each array element representing the
> value of `expression` on a 1-minute intrabar, ordered sequentially in
> time.